# How to bind spinner values properly?

Tags: python-2.7, spinner, kivy

I am trying to bind the values to the spinner through create_action function but not able to do it. Although, If i am calling those functions directly, it's working. Also I want the first value of spinner should be visible in the app, instead of empty space. Can anyone help in this?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

      self.spinner = Spinner( text = '0', value = ['0'], pos = (40, 50), 

      size=(100, 20))
      self.add_widget(self.spinner)

      self.spinner1 = Spinner(pos = (300, 50), size=(100, 20))
      self.add_widget(self.spinner1)

      self.create_action()

      #self.update_strokes(self.spinner1, text = 'None')
      #self.update_char_strokes(self.spinner, text = 'None')


   def create_action(self):
        #self.update_char_strokes(self.spinner, text = 'None')
        self.spinner.bind(text = self.update_char_strokes)
        self.spinner1.bind(text = self.update_strokes)

   def update_char_strokes(self, spinner, text):
        l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
        self.spinner.values = (map(str, range(len(l))))  
        print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> = ', len(l)


   def update_strokes(self, spinner1, text):
       l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
       self.spinner1.values = (map(str, range(len(l))))
       print '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> = ', len(l) 



class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind using `on_release` :

```
self.spinner.bind(on_release = self.update_char_strokes)
```

and eliminate the third arg in `update_strokes`:

```
def update_strokes(self, spinner1):
   l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
   self.spinner1.values = (map(str, range(len(l))))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot!  Now, I can see the values in spinner and I can select them. But still, when a spinner is displayed first time, I cannot see the first value :/ Its showing empty space.

Comment: @Pink do      `self.spinner1 = Spinner(text="0", pos = (300, 50), size=(100, 20))`

Comment: yes, I already did that. I thought, there might be some other way :) Thanks a lot !